# BizTalk | Issue with Logical Existence functoid | source node doesn’t exist, still need output in the target

Tags: biztalk

I have a requirement to populate the output field in the destination schema though the source field does not exist in the input XML. If it does not exist, I have different logic to populate the target field. I tried using the 'Logical Existence' functoid but it is not giving me the desired output.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560754/biztalk-2013r2-null-elements-in-schemas Use the Logical String, Logical Date or Logical number instead

Comment: Please provide schemas, a sample input, how you are mapping, output, and expected output.